# Memory Allocation of Instance Variables

Tags: heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory, static-memory-allocation

When we tell objects are created in heap memory and referenced in stack memory.
The reference to the Objects are in stack but where do the Instance variables lie.
Does each object have a collection on the heap memory?
And does the function call add on to the main stack??
In short I'd like to know the memory allocation of a program like this

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1gXh.png)

An overview of how all the memory allocation happens in an inheritence program.

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: The programming language : Java